# showing tooltip for html li element in firefox

Tags: asp.net, html

i want to show tooltip for individual li element for that i am using title attributes but it is working only in IE not n firefox and chrome what attribute should i use for these two browser

```
<ul class="steps">
                    <li class="" id="step1" runat="server" title="Element to Add / edit the Test">Step 1</li>
                    <li class="step2" id="step2" runat="server" title="Add Course Constituents">Step 2</li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute you are using is correct.  This element should be working for you and is part of HTML 4 and available on most elements.  [W3C Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#adef-title).  I did a simple test in both Firefox and Chrome and the title attribute on li is rendering as a tool tip for me.

Comment: you might try a jQuery plugin like qTip if you want more functionality.